# How can I achieve bash EXIT trap when exec-ing another binary?

Tags: bash, exec, bash-trap

I'd like to use a bash `EXIT` trap *and* use `exec` to avoid spawning a new process.  Is this possible?

That is,

```
#!/bin/bash
touch $0.$$
trap "rm -v $0.$$" EXIT
/bin/echo Hello
```

removes the temporary file `$0.$$` using bash's `EXIT` trap while

```
#!/bin/bash
touch $0.$$
trap "rm -v $0.$$" EXIT
exec /bin/echo Hello
```

never "fires" the trap (no message from `rm`, file `$0.$$` exists after completion).

It, of course, makes sense that the trap can't fire as bash is no longer in control after the `exec`.  Is there some way to make it work *and* use `exec`?  This is admittedly out of curiosity moreso than practical matters.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Generally, no. This is not possible for the reason you mention.

That's a boring answer though. Let's look at our options for workarounds:

If we care more about exec semantics and less about starting multiple processes, we can for arbitrary executables do:

```
{ while kill -0 $$; do sleep 5; done; rm "$0.$$"; } &
exec ./file
```

which will `exec` the file and have another process polling it and doing cleanup when it's done.

If we want to avoid forks and what we're executing is another shell script, we can do

```
exec bash --rcfile <(echo 'trap "..." exit') -i ./file
```

to `exec` the file and do the cleanup afterwards (as long as the script doesn't `exec` or override the trap), without starting a new process. `source`ing instead of `exec`ing will have much the same effect:

```
trap "..." exit
source ./file
```

If we want to get really hacky, we can use `LD_PRELOAD` to override `exit(3)` and run a command of our choice:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void exit(int c) {
    char* cmd = getenv("EXIT");
    char *argv[] = { "bash", "-c", cmd, NULL };
    char *envp[] = { NULL };
    execvpe("bash", argv, envp);
}
```

We can compile this as a library:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC foo.c -o libfoo.so
```

and then preload it into arbitrary, dynamically linked executables:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libfoo.so EXIT='echo "This is a hack"' ls *foo*
foo.c  libfoo.so
This is a hack
```

These hacks are fun, but rarely necessary in the real world. The simpler, better and more canonical solution is just to not `exec`.

Comment: Every time I think _"yeah, I've already seen the weirdest things that can be done with combinations of modern shell features,"_ and every time I am wrong.  +1

Answer (score 1):

gnu coreutil's `tail` has a parameter to wait for a process to exit

```
(tail --pid $$ -f /dev/null; ... ) &
exec ...
```