# Custom Git command dies from signal 13 (SIGPIPE) after exec'ing git diff

Tags: git, unix, process, signals, exec

If you create a shell script in your `PATH` called `git-mydiff` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec git diff
```

and call `git mydiff` in a repository with a large amount of changes, when you quit the pager, it will output:

```
error: git-mydiff died of signal 13
```

However, if you execute `path/to/git-mydiff` directly, there will be no error when you exit the pager.

Obviously one solution is to not use `exec`, but why is this a problem? Why is it only an issue when calling the script through the `git` proxy command?

I'm using: git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)

Comment: One possibility is to ignore SIGPIPE like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22464942/5781248

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. Because `exec` totally replaces the currently running program with a new one, I don't think signal traps are inherited. This is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111981/how-can-i-achieve-bash-exit-trap-when-exec-ing-another-binary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program, in this case `mydiff`, and the pager (`less`, or whatever you have selected as `core.pager`) are connected through a pipe.  The OS has some limit on the amount of data that can be written into a pipe before the reader must clean some out, and the pager doesn't read the entire pipe before pausing, so at some amount of output, the pipe has filled up and your program is blocked in its `write` system call.

If the read end of the pipe goes away (by having the pager exit), two things happen at this point: the OS delivers a `SIGPIPE` signal to your program, and the OS has the `write` system call fail with an `EPIPE` error.  Normally the first—the signal—kills your program before the second even occurs, but if your program were to catch or ignore `SIGPIPE`, the second would occur.

Here's an example in a job-control shell of `SIGPIPE` killing a process:

```
> cat book.pdf | : &
>
[1]    Broken pipe                   cat book.pdf |
       Done                          :
```

(Incidentally `:` here is the built in colon command, which is a no-op; it's a leftover from, I think, the Mashey shell that had `goto` as an external program.)  Running this as a regular foreground process, the sequence is silent:

```
> cat book.pdf | :
>
```

This is because the shell does not complain about the died-of-`SIGPIPE` process, since "died of `SIGPIPE`" is quite normal.

For whatever reason, the `git` front end is noisier about this died-of-`SIGPIPE` case.  If you don't use `exec`, it is the *shell* that sees the died-of-`SIGPIPE`.  The shell absorbs that quietly and exits cleanly and git does not complain.  If you *do* use `exec`, the shell is replaced with your program, and the `git` front end command sees the died-of-`SIGPIPE` status and complains.

One obvious cure is to leave the shell around.  Another approach is to get the shell to *ignore* (not catch) `SIGPIPE`, then do the `exec`:

```
trap "" PIPE
```

As you [noted in a comment-reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117004/custom-git-command-dies-from-signal-13-sigpipe-after-execing-git-diff#comment57954993_35117004), *catching* `SIGPIPE` is no good: since `exec` replaces the current occupant of the address space, the OS resets all *caught* signals to their default disposition (which for `SIGPIPE` is "die of signal").  However, *ignored* signals remain ignored.

Depending on your program, this may be as bad or worse.  For instance, when `cat` dies of `SIGPIPE` the shell is silent, but when `cat` sees `write` fail with `EPIPE` it complains:

```
$ cat book.pdf | :
$ trap "" PIPE
$ cat book.pdf | :
cat: stdout: Broken pipe
```

(this is on FreeBSD; different OSes vary slightly, depending on how careful and clever their utilities are).

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation! If I add `trap "" PIPE` to the script before `exec git diff`, I still see "died of signal 13" when `less` exits. Shouldn't it now be failing due to `EPIPE` rather than `SIGPIPE`?

Comment: It should, yes (unless it's doing something weird like explicitly resetting the signal to default).  Might be interesting to dump out the syscalls being made (trace, truss, ktrace, whatever the OS provides...).